# Setting the parameter for multilearn in pyBKT

Tags: python, scikit-multilearn

I want to run pyBKT on the assistment data with a multilearn model and get the warning: `'multilearn default column not specified'`.
This is my code:

```
model = Model(seed = SEED, parallel = True)    
%time model.fit(data=df_train, skills=SKILLS, multilearn = True)
```

How does one specify the default column?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer: specify in multilearn the column to be used. So instead of
`multilearn = True`, use `multilearn = "columnID"`.